# How can I convert time from seconds to decimal year in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime, time

I have a dataset which includes the seconds that have passed since 2000-01-01 00:00:00.0 and I would like them to be converted to decimal years (for example 2013.87).

An example from the dataset:

```
416554767.293262
416554768.037637
416554768.782013
416554769.526386
416554770.270761
416554771.015136
416554771.759509
416554772.503884
416554773.248258
416554773.992632
416554774.737007
416554775.481381
416554776.225757
416554776.970131
416554777.714504
416554778.458880
```

Can anyone help me out on this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to perform these computations using methods of [`datetime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) and [`duration`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html). A bit like this. I've tried to be careful regarding the number of seconds / year, since of course that varies depending on whether the year in question is a leap year.

```
% Original data
data = [416554767.293262
416554768.037637
416554768.782013
416554769.526386
416554770.270761
416554771.015136
416554771.759509
416554772.503884
416554773.248258
416554773.992632
416554774.737007
416554775.481381
416554776.225757
416554776.970131
416554777.714504
416554778.458880];

% Original data is seconds since 'base':
base = datetime(2000,1,1);
% Get datetimes corresponding to 'data'
dates = base + seconds(data);
% Extract the year portion from the dates
wholeYears = year(dates);
% Extract the remainder of the dates as seconds
remainderInSeconds = seconds(dates - datetime(wholeYears,1,1));
% Calculate the number of seconds in each of the years
secondsPerYear = seconds(datetime(wholeYears + 1, 1, 1) - datetime(wholeYears, 1, 1));
% Final result is whole years + remainder expressed as years
result = wholeYears + (remainderInSeconds ./ secondsPerYear);
fprintf('%.16f\n', result);
```